# Perform function until it returns user-error

Tags: org-mode, elisp, error-handling

I want to define a function `org-move-subtree-top` that calls `org-move-subtree-up` until it returns a `user-error` (in this case "Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit"). How can I do this in elisp?

Answer (score 2):

Write an infinite loop, and catch the error outside the loop.

```
(condition-case nil
    (while t
      (org-move-subtree-up))
  (error nil))
```

Org mode 7.8.11 throws a plain `error` for this message. If you have a more recent version that calls `user-error` instead of `error`, replace `error` by `user-error`.

This hides all errors. It would be safer to catch only the specific error that you intended to happen, but that requires hard-coding the error message.

```
(condition-case err
    (while t
      (org-move-subtree-up))
  (error (or (equal (cdr err) "Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit")
             (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))
```

Alternatively, you could implement this without calling `org-move-subtree-up`: find the boundaries of the subtree, find the target position, and move it there. Untested.

```
(defun org-move-subtree-top ()
  "Move the current subtree just after the heading of its parent."
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((target (save-excursion
                   (org-back-to-heading)
                   (outline-up-heading)
                   (forward-line)
                   (point)))
        (beg (progn
               (org-back-to-heading)
               (point))
        (end (progn
               (org-end-of-subtree)
               (point)))
        (text (buffer-substring beg end)))
    (delete-region text)
    (goto-char target)
    (insert text)))
```

Comment: The first snippet is essentially just `ignore-errors`. in order to only catch user errors (as the OP asked) you can replace the `(error nil)` with `(user-error nil)`.

Comment: @Malabarba The Org mode version I have on my machine calls `(error "Cannot move past superior level or buffer limit")`. If newer versions call `user-error` then indeed `error` should be replaced by `user-error` in my snippet.